# Is this covariant derivative compatible with the Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Tags: differential-geometry, geodesic, connections

I'm currently learning about metrics and covariant derivatives in differential geometry, and I can't figure out if the following form of covariant derivatives on $\mathbb{R}^2$ satisfy the conditions for "metric compatibility" or not (with respect to the usual Euclidean metric):

$$
\begin{align}
\nabla_X X &= \alpha Y \\
\nabla_X Y &= -\alpha X \\
\nabla_Y X &= \beta Y \\
\nabla_Y Y &= -\beta X
\end{align}
$$

Which, if I understand correctly, is equivalent to:

$$
\begin{align}
\nabla_X \tilde{Y} &= \alpha \tilde{X} \\
\nabla_X \tilde{X} &= -\alpha \tilde{Y} \\
\nabla_Y \tilde{Y} &= \beta \tilde{X} \\
\nabla_Y \tilde{X} &= -\beta \tilde{Y}
\end{align}
$$

Where $X$ and $Y$ are the standard basis vector fields, $\tilde{X}$ and $\tilde{Y}$ are the dual basis one-forms, and $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are arbitrary manifold functions $\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$.

To the best of my understanding, this covariant derivative satisfies $\nabla g = 0$ (where $g$ is the Euclidean metric tensor) and is therefore a metric connection (but not the unique torsion-free Levi-Civita connection), because applying the tensor product rule gives:

$$
\begin{align}
\nabla_X g
&=
\nabla_X \left( \tilde{X} \otimes \tilde{X} + \tilde{Y} \otimes \tilde{Y} \right) \\
&=
\left( \nabla_X \tilde{X} \right) \otimes \tilde{X}
+
\tilde{X} \otimes \left( \nabla_X \tilde{X} \right)
+
\left( \nabla_X \tilde{Y} \right) \otimes \tilde{Y}
+
\tilde{Y} \otimes \left( \nabla_X \tilde{Y} \right)
\\
&=
-\alpha \tilde{Y} \otimes {X} - \alpha \tilde{X} \otimes \tilde{Y}
+
\alpha \tilde{X} \otimes \tilde{Y} + \alpha \tilde{Y} \otimes \tilde{X}
\\
&= 0
\end{align}
$$

And similarly for $\nabla_Y$:

$$
\begin{align}
\nabla_Y g
&=
\nabla_Y \left( \tilde{X} \otimes \tilde{X} + \tilde{Y} \otimes \tilde{Y} \right) \\
&=
\left( \nabla_Y \tilde{X} \right) \otimes \tilde{X}
+
\tilde{X} \otimes \left( \nabla_Y \tilde{X} \right)
+
\left( \nabla_Y \tilde{Y} \right) \otimes \tilde{Y}
+
\tilde{Y} \otimes \left( \nabla_Y \tilde{Y} \right)
\\
&=
-\beta \tilde{Y} \otimes {X} - \beta \tilde{X} \otimes \tilde{Y}
+
\beta \tilde{X} \otimes \tilde{Y} + \beta \tilde{Y} \otimes \tilde{X}
\\
&= 0
\end{align}
$$

However, this connection seems (although I am not sure) as though it would give rise to geodesics which are not straight lines when $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are nonzero, which contradicts other definitions of metric compatibility I have heard.  So, my questions are:

1. Is the covariant derivative defined above compatible with the Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{R}^2$, or am I misunderstanding something about metric compatibility?
2. If it is compatible, what kind of behavior does parallel transport exhibit under this connection?
3. In particular, do nonzero $\alpha$ and $\beta$ produce geodesics which are not straight lines?

Comment: Are you sure you want $\nabla_Y Y = -\beta Y$ and not $\nabla_Y Y = -\beta X$ (or something) in your fourth equation?  Because I think it might make ***hella*** difference!

Comment: I'm also curious as to whether $\nabla_Y Y = - \beta Y$ and $\nabla_Y {\tilde Y} =\beta {\tilde X}$ etc. are consistent

Comment: $-\beta Y$ was a typo -- thanks for pointing it out!  Fixed now.

Comment: Now it makes ***hella*** more sense!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not going to relate to your specific covariant derivative, but rather quote a few definitions and state a few basic claims regarding your questions.

1) By definition, the connection $\nabla$ is *metric* or *compatible with the metric* if it satisfies $\nabla g=0$.

2) Equivalently, the connection $\nabla$ is metric if and only if the parallel transport it induces preserves the Riemannian metric.

3) Geodesics with respect to a metric connection $\nabla$ are not, in general, the same as geodesics with respect to the Levi-Civita connection.